# Multiple Lines With 3 Quotes in Python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot which sends an embed message with a square walls inside of it. I can make the left, up and down walls but don't know how to make the right one. If i use the code like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="hello", description=""":green_square::green_square::green_square:
        :green_square:
        :green_square::green_square::green_square:""", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

This is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gipso.jpg

And with this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="hello", description=""":green_square::green_square::green_square:
        :green_square:              :green_square:
        :green_square::green_square::green_square:""", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZols.jpg

Comment: Replace the space zone with another symbol ?

Comment: do you mean something like this
```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="hello", description=""":green_square::green_square::green_square:
        :green_square::green_square::green_square:
        :green_square::green_square::green_square:""", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Discord you can't put text/emojis on the x-axis where you want. This is done by the text-renderer.
Keep in mind, Discord's emojis are uniform in size. Which means all emojis have the same height, and width. So if you want a perfect sqaure, you will need a emoji in the 3x3 center. Maybe `:black_large_square:`?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('a'):
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="hello", description=""":green_square::green_square::green_square:
        :green_square::black_large_square::green_square:
        :green_square::green_square::green_square:""", color=0x00ff00)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Otherwise, you are able to use markdown "```", to use a monospace font (not only emojis, but also characters are the same size). However, this would display emojis in utf-8 so I guess thats not what you want. Best option for your case would be to put a nondescript emoji like `:black_large_square:` inside the 3x3 square.

Comment: I was going to fill it up later anyway until i do that i can use this thank you